# ASP MVC Relative URL Path(not file)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a link to `<a href='/ViewReport'>` on my local host that works fine, but on the server the whole site is in a folder "serverfolder", so the link becomes `http://somesite/serverfolder/ViewReport`, which isn't a valid url. I have seen how to use ~ to access the root directory for files, but not how to do this with url paths. I want to use the same link for both local and remote deployment. How would I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Where are you actually trying to use link in code? Its Razor view or *.js file or something else?

Comment: In a controller. So it looks like " String link = "<a href='/ViewReport?userid=" + UserName + "&reportid=" + PI.ElementAt(i).TempUserID + "' class='btn mini purple'><i class='icon-edit'></i>View/Edit</a>"; 
This link then gets added to a table. So the dynamic link I am creating is pointing to a non-existent url on the remote server.

Comment: You've tagged this .NET and "classic" - which is it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using @Html.ActionLink()?

Comment: That was an accident sorry. This is ASP MVC.

Comment: I am generating the link in the controller not the view. Would using ActionLink solve some issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
   + urlHelper.Action("ViewReport", 
     new { userId = UserName, reportId = PI.ElementAt(i).TempUserID });
```

Or, if you prefer not to use the UrlHelper.Action, you do it like this:

```
string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/ViewReport...";
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Had no idea those methods even existed. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnEdwards - Here's a thought, perhaps you should Read the docs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd566232(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MystereMan You have read through all of the MSDN docs on BCL, ASP.NET, MVC, and all of the other Microsoft frameworks you use?

Comment: No need to be testy. There's 70+ classes, all with a multitude of methods. It takes a large chunk of time to experiment with multiple things. That is kind of the point of SO. Making information more easily accessible.

Comment: @JohnEdwards - Indeed, but there's a difference between not knowing what they all do, and not knowing they even exist.

Comment: @AaronLS - MVC is not a very large set of classes

Comment: Well maybe someday I will acquire your godlike knowledge of MVC, but as I have less than a month of experience with it, it is probably not surprising I didn't know certain functionality existed.

Comment: @MystereMan But there's more to the framework than just MVC.  Where do you draw the line on what parts of MSDN someone should or should not have been expected to have read?  You could reply with RTFM to just about everything on stackoverflow.  Doesn't make it constructive nor justify being flippant.

Comment: @AaronLS - When asking about an MVC question, I would expect you to have read the docs on MVC.

Comment: @MystereMan Why not expect them to have read the rest of MSDN that MVC falls under and could potentially hold a solution to the problem?  ASP.NET?  BCL?  All of those contain components that deal in one way or another with URLs. Your expectations are silly and your attitude unjustified and unconstructive.  Let me tell you about my expectations, that people like you keep your expectations to yourself.

Comment: @AaronLS - Well, you have your opinions, and I have mine.

Comment: @MystereMan The difference is you can convey yours like an adult without being flippant.